# How to push postgresql to docker hub

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to upload my project to docker hub. I followed this tutorial https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/. I use docker-compose and it works great for me, but I cannot upload it to the docker hub. I am using docker-compose push and it only pushes a project image without a base. I would like the base to also go to the dockhub

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to push the db image, you haven't made any changes to the base image?

Comment: The `postgres` image is already on Docker Hub; you don't need to separately push it.